# How to count frequency in one column based on unique values in another column in R?

Tags: r, count, unique, frequency

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
   Product Patient_ID
1        A          1
2        A          1
3        A          1
4        A          3
5        D          3
6        D          4
7        D          5
8        E          5
9        E          6
10       F          7
11       G          8
```

Where I'd like to count the number of **unique** individuals who have used a product. In other words, I would like to get a frequency for the 'Product' column, based on unique 'Patient IDs'.

My desired dataset would look something like this:

```
  Product Freq
1       A    2
2       D    3
3       E    2
4       F    1
5       G    1
```

How can I go about doing this?

Reproducible data:

```
test_data<-data.frame(Product=c("A","A","A","A","D","D","D","E","E","F","G"),Patient_ID=c("1","1","1","3","3","4","5","5","6","7","8"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

you first load the tidyverse package

Use the distinct() function  to get the distinct values in the columns, then group the column based on the Products names and Use the summarize () function to get the unique count frequency

```
 unique_count <- test_data %<% distinct(Product,Patient_ID) %<% group_by(Product)%>% summarize ("Freq" = n())
```

This should get you the result

Answer (score 0):

base R solution:
you can first remove duplicates with the **!duplicated** function remove the merged column's value using the **paste0** function, then, use **table** for the product column.

```
rez<-as.data.frame(table(test_data[!duplicated(paste0(test_data$Product,test_data$Patient_ID)),"Product"]))
colnames(rez)[1]<-"Product"
```

If you have only these two column you can skip the **paste0** and do:

```
rez<-as.data.frame(table(test_data[!duplicated(test_data),"Product"]))
```

Comment: Or just `data.frame(table(Product = unique(test_data)$Product))`